# Average amount between numbers in PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a database like this:

```
ACTIONS
id   day   name
1    4     Bill
2    8     Susan
3    10    Bill
4    12    Bill
5    18    Susan
6    22    John
```

I want to get the average amount of days or latency between 2 records grouped by name.

**Example with Bill**
Calculation Steps

1. Days Between 10 - 4 = 6
2. Days Between 12 - 10 = 2
3. Average = 4

**Example with Susan**
Calculation Steps

1. Days Between 18 - 8 = 10
2. Average = 10

Since John has only one record there is no time between so it should return 0 or null either way is fine.

So i'm looking to write a query which does those calculation steps and returns the following dataset:

```
RESULTS
name       average_days_between
Bill       4
Susan      10
John       null
```

I was able to write a script that looped through each record and averaged out the calculation one at a time but with a large set of records it takes to long to generate.

Is it possible to write a PostgreSQL query which generates a result set like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lag()` window function will do this for you.  If it's too slow, then rewrite the `intervals` CTE as a subquery.

```
with actions (id, day, name) as (
  values (1, 4, 'Bill'),
         (2, 8, 'Susan'),
         (3, 10, 'Bill'),
         (4, 12, 'Bill'),
         (5, 18, 'Susan'),
         (6, 22, 'John')
), intervals as (
  select name,
         day -
           lag(day)
             over (partition by name
                       order by day) as latency
  from actions
)
select name,
       avg(latency) as avg_latency,
       count(*) as observations
  from intervals
 where latency is not null
 group by name
 order by name;

┌───────┬─────────────────────┬──────────────┐
│ name  │     avg_latency     │ observations │
├───────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────┤
│ Bill  │  4.0000000000000000 │            2 │
│ Susan │ 10.0000000000000000 │            1 │
└───────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────┘
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I had a similar idea, but much more complicated. Neat usage of `lag`!